# Common date format function for Oracle-sql and Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, date, format

I need to write the common queries for MySQL and Oracle databases. Problem occurs when I have to put date conditions.
For example: there is one field `Txn_date` which is in format of `'20150116'` in MySQL and `'16-JAN-2015'` in Oracle.

I use `date_format(now(),'%Y%m%d')` for MySQL and `to_char(sysdate,'dd-MON-YYYY')` for Oracle.

Is there any common function of way by which I can use the same function in both Oracle and MySQL?

I tried `Txn_date in ( date_format(now(),'%Y%m%d') OR to_char(sysdate,'dd-MON-YYYY') )` but did not work because `to_char()` not recognized in MySQL.

Comment: You are using the exact same queries on both database platforms?

Comment: If you're working with dates, why are you converting them to strings in order to compare them?

Comment: @Siyual: Yes I am using the exact queries

Comment: @DavidFaber: This is how the date is configured in database

Comment: @Jagdeep, that is not how the dates are configured in the database. The dates are stored as dates, not strings.

Comment: @DavidFaber: But while query I have to enter like this in the sqldeveloper or say terminal

Comment: @Jagdeep, I understand, sorry for being pedantic. Please see my answer below, maybe it will be of help to you.

Comment: @DavidFaber: Thanks a lot David. your suggestion helped me and will help a lot in future .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in MySQL dates usually have the following format when converted implicitly - `2015-01-16` - rather than `20150116`. I think you can do the following in both MySQL *and* Oracle (it is standard SQL) - I've checked it in Oracle (10g) and it works, and it seems to work [in my fiddling with MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/52185):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE mydate IN ( DATE '2015-01-16', DATE '2015-01-18' );
```

The string literal to be converted to DATE has to be of the form `yyyy-mm-dd`. Now this will work if your dates are *dates* and don't have a time portion. Now if your dates do have a time portion, then things become more difficult since MySQL uses the `DATE()` function to get the date portion, while Oracle would use `TRUNC()`. But you can get around that with judicious use of `>=` and `<`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE ( mydate >= DATE '2015-01-16' AND mydate < DATE '2015-01-17' )
    OR ( mydate >= DATE '2015-01-18' AND mydate < DATE '2015-01-19' );
```

Now if you want to use `SYSDATE`, the best thing to do would be to use the ANSI standard `CURRENT_DATE` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. These can be compared directly with no need for formatting and should work in both MySQL and Oracle. You can also do date arithmetic using `INTERVAL`, in which case you could try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE mydate > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

**UPDATE** I've been doing some thinking about this. The query immediately above doesn't really work if you want to get all the rows that have been entered *today*. The difficulty is that Oracle recognizes ANSI date literals as dates (that is, with no time portion), but there isn't, as far as I know, an ANSI-standard way of converting a *date/time* value (which an Oracle `DATE` is) to a *date*. That said, both Oracle and MySQL support the EXTRACT() function, so you should be able to do the following to get *today*'s records:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM mydate) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)
   AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM mydate) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)
   AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM mydate) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE);
```

Definitely unwieldy, especially if one has more than one date to consider (which I assume you do since you're using the `IN` operator), but should work on both platforms. [See SQL Fiddle Demo here (MySQL)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c089b/1) and [here (Oracle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a17a2/1).

Comment: @Jagdeep, I updated my answer - hopefully in a way that is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL and Oracle use different syntax for converting dates to strings - you'll have to use different queries.

Comment: Please see my answer - one can use ANSI standard date functions in both MySQL and Oracle. It won't be pretty but it will work.