# Is there any common function for formatting date in SQL Server and Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, date-format, date-formatting

I am building an application and need to format the datetime field to dd/mm. I was using `TO_CHAR` in Oracle and which is not supported in SQL Server and got error when it is deployed with SQL Server database.

Is the any common function which can be used across different databases for formatting the datetime field to a format passed by user.

`Format` is supported in SQL Server and `TO_CHAR` is Oracle. I want to have a common method, since I dodn't know which database my application will be deployed.

Comment: No there is no such function. You will need to write your own.

Comment: how do you create an index or a table?

Comment: There is no common function. SQL Server doesn't even support the ANSI standard `EXTRACT()` function.

Comment: What does your application use on the front end? It would probably be best to do the formatting there.

Comment: Are you aware that a `DATE` in Oracle _includes_ a time? Whereas in SQL Server it doesn't? And Oracle doesn't have a `datetime` data type but it uses `TIMESTAMP`? Writing SQL that will work without any changes on both systems will limit you to an extent that you probably can't really do anything with that application.

Comment: Yes, I am building an application on top of a platform where I define the entities and it is taking care about the column type based on the model defined there. Only issue is when I define chart based reports I have to group the data based on date where I need to define my own wrapper function for that field inside SELECT method. So I don't have much flexibility to define my own function directly in the database server.

Comment: I submit the following to show how difficult it is to accomplish this even when two DBMSs support ANSI-standard date functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992138/common-date-format-function-for-oracle-sql-and-mysql

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such function to format `DATE` which is **common** to both **Oracle** and **SQL Server**.

You could write your own function for this.

For example, In **Oracle** you could have an **user defined function** as `FORMAT`.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2    FUNCTION format(
  3        dt DATE)
  4      RETURN VARCHAR2
  5    IS
  6      l_str VARCHAR2(20);
  7    BEGIN
  8      SELECT TO_CHAR(dt, 'DD/MM') INTO l_str FROM dual;
  9      RETURN l_str;
 10    END;
 11    /

Function created.

SQL> sho err
No errors.
SQL> SELECT format(sysdate) FROM DUAL;

FORMAT(SYSDATE)
----------------------------------------------------------
30/03

SQL>
```

Comment: Even if I write my own function, need to have a common way to convert the date-time to formatted string inside my function. Because in my case I cannot have different deployment based on the database server. So my function should be capable enough to run differently based on the database.

Comment: See my update in the answer. You could write your user defined function.

Comment: @nish "*Because in my case I cannot have different deployment based on the database server*"  - that is **not** going to work. It's like saying: "*I'm trying to write a web application but it should be independent of the application framework I'm using*"